# Updating line items through code in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I'm trying to make an interface where I can edit some of the metadata attached to a lineitem. I've tried using update_post_meta() on the line item itself, however that returns bool(false). How can I update the line item meta data manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us some code you've tried.

Comment: I actually managed to figure it out. I'll post my solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I managed to figure it out. I wrote a small function that's below. So, all you need to do is load up the order using the API, parse through each line item and you can call wc_update_order_item_meta. The only thing is, you need to know the variation ID of the item being sold if you only want to update a specific item.

```
function update_order_item_meta($orderID, $variationID, $metaID, $metaValue) {
$order = returnWC_API()->get_order($orderID)->{'order'};
if(!$order) {
    return false;
}
if($variationID == "all") {
    foreach ($order->{'line_items'} as $line_item) {
        if(!wc_update_order_item_meta($line_item->{'id'}, $metaID, $metaValue)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

foreach ($order->{'line_items'} as $line_item) {
    if($line_item->{'product_id'} == $variationID) {
        return wc_update_order_item_meta($line_item->{'id'}, $metaID, $metaValue);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: late to question but - which woocommerce hook did you use or what point did you call this function? how did you get metaID ?